# How to avoid patterns when making random perlin noise

Tags: c++, random, 3d, perlin-noise

I am making a 3d perlin noise generator.  It is important that the coordinate is the seed so that it gives me the same random value every time (the noise is never stored). This is my function for generating random values based on a seed which is the coordinate:

```
__forceinline float getRandomField(const vec3& Position) const
{
    uint32_t seed = uint32_t(Position.x);
    seed <<= 8;
    seed ^= 0xE56FAA12;
    seed |= uint32_t(Position.y);
    seed <<= 8;
    seed ^= 0x69628a2d;
    seed |= uint32_t(Position.z);
    seed <<= 8;
    seed ^= 0xa7b2c49a;

    srand(seed);

    return (float(int(rand()%2001) -1000)/1000.0f);
}
```

Result (a slice in the x,y plane):

[image: Perlin noise with undesired pattern]

Weirdly enough, this gives me a pattern. Obviously, I have no idea what I'm doing. I though that apply some weird xor values and bit shifting into a random seed would give me a random number. Apparently I was wrong.

What is the best way to create a random value from a coordinate without it resulting in a pattern?

Comment: A *slow* way would to hash the concatenation of the 3 positions [e.g. hash your seed ignoring the xor bits] (using say md5) and pull out the lowest 2 bytes. Would work though.

Comment: I has to be (relatively) fast aswell. I don't know anything about md5 but I saw some code for a md5 generator at it was on 536 lines. That is way to slow.

Comment: Here's an interesting pdf on noise from oregon state http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mjb/cs519/Handouts/noise.1pp.pdf

Comment: Why not just seed the RNG once, and generate values in a fixed order? That's enough for reproducibility.

Comment: Generating values in a fixed order is not an option. Generating the picture is just for testing. In reality it will be used to generate the terrain as the viewer apporaches. With no hard limits to the world, it is imposible to store evertything and therefore impossible to be sure the samples are generated the same if you only seed once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give a answer to other people who might have the same problem. I found one that produced a pretty good result. I didn't even need the rand() function.

```
__forceinline float getRandomField(const vec3& Position) const
{
    uint32_t seed = uint32_t(Position.x)*1087;
    seed ^= 0xE56FAA12;
    seed += uint32_t(Position.y)*2749;
    seed ^= 0x69628a2d;
    seed += uint32_t(Position.z)*3433;
    seed ^= 0xa7b2c49a;

    return (float(int(seed%2001) -1000)/1000.0f);
}
```

The key is to multiply each axis with a prime number. I found these on wikipedia:
1087,2749,3433.
The hex values xor'ed with is just randomly hammered down by me. They are not primes, as far as I know. Check out the result:

[image: Not bad huh?]

Comment: I've used perlin noise for a little while and I know that its important to use prime numbers, but never *why* prime numbers are key. Do you have any incite into this?

Comment: @RichardTingle I believe this is because the primes are not divisible by each other.  Of you have a grid that plots a point for each multiple of a prime number you get less likelyhood of overlap.  http://io9.com/5895840/why-do-cicadas-know-prime-numbers